# How to properly do something onUpdate of firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why Am I getting error in this code block?

```
var current_op_id = 0;

var targetRef = firebase.database().ref('operators/' + current_op_id);

    targetRef.onUpdate((change, context) => {
        //do something here
    });
```

`Error: Uncaught TypeError: targetRef.onUpdate is not a function`

Just before that code block, I have this code block that works OK.

```
var op_id = 0;

var updatedRef = firebase.database().ref('operators/' + op_id);

    updatedRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        //do something here

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`onUpdate()` is used in cloud functions, from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events):

> `onUpdate()`, which triggers when data is updated in the Realtime Database.

```
exports.dbUpdate = functions.database.ref('/path').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const beforeData = change.before.val();
  const afterData = change.after.val(); 
});
```

If you want to update a field in Realtime Database, then you need to use `update()`. You can read more about it here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: I have a textbox on a simple html/javascript page that display realtime data from firebase realtime database. I want to run a function when this textbox gets new data from firebase.